# How do I implement a pruning strategy with a DTW algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, pruning

I've tried to implement a DTW algorithm for a speech recognition application, which I've done successfully, and I'm now trying to improve the performance of the DTW algorithm by pruning. I've tried searching for an improvement to this algorithms and found that I'm supposed to somehow calculate the values in the 2D array `DTW` in a specific range as shown in `Image #1`, but I don't seem to know exactly how to do that. Could someone provide any help with that?
The code to the algorithm is included (C#)
[image: Sakoe-Chiba band and Ikatora Parallelogram]

---

```
/// <summary>
///   Calculates the distance between two audio frames in the form of two MFCCFrame objects as input parameters
///   returns the difference in a double
/// </summary>

double distance(MFCCFrame frame1, MFCCFrame frame2)
{
    double tempSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        tempSum += Math.Pow(Math.Abs(frame1.Features[i] - frame2.Features[i]), 2);
    return Math.Sqrt(tempSum);
}

/// <summary>
///   DTW Algorithms
///   Takes input 2 sequences: seq1 and seq2 to calculate the shortest distance between them
///   Uses the function "distance" defined above to calculate distance between two frames
///   2D array -> DTW[,] with dimentions: number of frames in seq 1, number of frames in seq2
///   returns the last element in the 2D array, which is the difference between the two sequences
/// </summary>

double DTWDistance(Sequence seq1, Sequence seq2)
{
    int m = seq1.Frames.Length, n = seq2.Frames.Length;
    double[,] DTW = new double[m, n];
    DTW[0, 0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            double cost = distance(seq1.Frames[i], seq2.Frames[j]);
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                DTW[i, j] = cost;
            else if (i == 0)
                DTW[i, j] = cost + DTW[i, j - 1];
            else if (j == 0)
                DTW[i, j] = cost + DTW[i - 1, j];
            else
                DTW[i, j] = (cost + Math.Min(DTW[i - 1, j], Math.Min(DTW[i, j - 1], DTW[i - 1, j - 1])));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not getting good anwers here, there is http://dsp.stackexchange.com for signal processing-related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one answered, I thought I'd answer this in case anyone needed help with this as well
This is the regular DTW algorithm:

```
/// <summary>
///   DTW Algorithms
///   Takes input 2 sequences: input and template to calculate the shortest distance between them
///   Uses the function "distance" defined above to calculate distance between two frames
///   2D array -> DTW[,] with dimentions: number of frames in input, number of frames in template
///   returns the last element in the 2D array, which is the difference between the two sequences
/// </summary>
/// 
double DTWDistance(Sequence input, Sequence template)
{
    int rows = input.Frames.Length, columns = template.Frames.Length;
    if (rows < (double)(columns / 2) || columns < (double)(rows / 2))
    {
        return double.MaxValue;
    }
        double[,] DTW = new double[rows, columns];
    DTW[0, 0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            double cost = distance(input.Frames[i], template.Frames[j]);
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                DTW[i, j] = cost;
            else if (i == 0)
                DTW[i, j] = cost + DTW[i, j - 1];
            else if (j == 0)
                DTW[i, j] = cost + DTW[i - 1, j];
            else
                DTW[i, j] = (cost + Math.Min(DTW[i - 1, j], DTW[i - 1, j - 1]));// insert ,match
        }
    }
    return DTW[rows - 1, columns - 1];
}
```

And I've also implemented a pruning strategy on the regular DTW algorithms, it's shown here:

```
/// <summary>
/// DTW Algotithm with Pruning
/// Only Sakoe-Chiba band is caluculated and the rest is pruned
/// </summary>
float Pruning_DTWDistance(Sequence input, Sequence output)
{
    int rows = input.Frames.Length, columns = output.Frames.Length;
    if (rows < (double)(columns / 2) || columns < (double)(rows / 2))
    {
        return float.MaxValue;
    }
    float cost;
    float[,] DTW = new float[rows + 1, columns + 1];
    int w = Math.Abs(columns - rows);// window length -> |rows - columns|<= w
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = Math.Max(1, i - w); j <= Math.Min(columns, i + w); j++)
        {
            if (DTW[i - 1, j] == 0)
                DTW[i - 1, j] = float.MaxValue;
            if (DTW[i - 1, j - 1] == 0)
                DTW[i - 1, j - 1] = float.MaxValue;
            DTW[0, 0] = 0;
            cost = distance(input.Frames[i - 1], output.Frames[j - 1]);// frames 0 based
            DTW[i, j] = (cost + Math.Min(DTW[i - 1, j], DTW[i - 1, j - 1]));// insert ,match
        }
    }
    return DTW[rows, columns];
}
```

Both functions use a helper function `distance`, which is defined as follows:

```
/// <summary>
///   Calculates the distance between two audio frames in the form of MFCCFrame objects
///   returns the difference in a float
/// </summary>
/// 
float distance(MFCCFrame frame1, MFCCFrame frame2)
{
    double tempSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        tempSum += Math.Pow(Math.Abs(frame1.Features[i] - frame2.Features[i]), 2);
    return (float)Math.Sqrt(tempSum);
}
```

[EDIT]
In order to improve the memory consumption of the DTW algoritm, I have used only 2 arrays instead of a 2D matrix, the algorithm after this change is shown here:

```
    double DTW_improved(Sequence input, Sequence template)
    {
        // Don't compare two sequences if one of their lengths is half the other's
        if (input.Frames.Length <= (0.5 * template.Frames.Length) || template.Frames.Length <= (0.5 * input.Frames.Length))
            return double.PositiveInfinity;
        int rows = template.Frames.Length, columns = input.Frames.Length;

        double[] c1 = new double[rows];
        double[] c2 = new double[rows];
        double[] temp; // To hold address only (use it in swapping address) 
        c1[0] = distance(input.Frames[0], template.Frames[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
            c1[i] = c1[i - 1] + distance(input.Frames[0], template.Frames[i]);
        for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++)
        {
            c2[0] = distance(input.Frames[i], template.Frames[0]) + c1[0];
            c2[1] = distance(input.Frames[i], template.Frames[1]) + Math.Min(c1[0], c1[1]); 
            // Calculating first 2 elements of the array before the loop
            //since they both need special conditions
            for (int j = 2; j < rows; j++)
                c2[j] = Math.Min(c1[j], Math.Min(c1[j - 1], c1[j - 2])) + distance(input.Frames[i], template.Frames[j]);

            if (i != columns - 1) // Swapping addresses of c1 & c2
            {
                temp = c2;
                c2 = c1;
                c1 = temp;
            }
        }
        return c2[rows - 1] / (0.5 * (input.Frames.Length + template.Frames.Length)); // Normalization: Dividing edit distance by average of input length & template length
    }
```